# Can you do distributed transactions across Azure SQL and Azure Cosmos Db?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I have an C# application where my domain transactions are stored in Azure SQL.  My event store I would like to utilize Azure Cosmos DB.  I am wondering if a distributed transaction across them will work?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Of course a distributed transaction will work if you implement it correctly.

Comment: @MoB. I couldnt find anywhere that Cosmos DB supports XA.

Comment: @MikeLenart - there simply isn't any cross-database-service transaction support.

Answer (score 0):

Of course distributed transactions *work* across whatever systems, if implemented correctly. But actually implementing a full architecture for a distributed atomic commit protocol with transaction managers is a daunting task.

If you mean built-in support in Azure - no, there is no support for that. There is only very limited support for transactions even within a single Cosmos DB container.

Comment: Not sure about saying "of course" - there is no support at all for distributed transactions across different Azure database services. There is no "implement correctly" - there is no rollback support in Cosmos DB. This is not a trivial undertaking by any means.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I totally agree. I edited the answer to make it clearer that it's non-trivial in practice, but in theory there is no reason why Cosmos DB as a participant of a correctly implemented distributed transaction architecture shouldn't "work".